# Lagrange Polynomials Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, lagrange-interpolation

I'd appreciate some help with this problem! My professor in my graduate linear algebra class is giving us some tough homework.

$$P(x) = p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + .... + a_nx^{n}$$ such that $a_i$ is real numbers

a.) Show that $P(x)$ is a vector space under the pointwise definition of vector addition and scalar multiplication.

b.) Show that the set $Q = \{q(x) = x^k$ such that $k = 0,1,....,n\}$ of monomials of order $k \le n$ form a basis for $P(x)$.

c.) Fix a set of a distinct points $x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n$ in the reals and define the mapping

$K: p(x)| -> (p(x_0) p(x_1) ... p(x_n))$ Note: (this is a column vector)
From P(x) to the reals of dimension n + 1. Show that this mapping has no kernal in P(x) and must be invertible.

d.) Using the formula for Lagrange polynomials of order n, calculate the column vector $K_{c_k}$ for each $k = 0,\dots,n$, and use this result to give an inverse mapping $K^{-1}$. Reals of dimension $n -> P(x)$.

There's just a lot here and it's getting to me. A little bit of guidance would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I present hints and then solutions.

Hints:
a. You need to show adding two polynomials of order $<=n$ yields a polynomial of order $<=n$. Also you need to show multiplying a polynomial of order $n$ with any real number yields a polynomial of order $<=n$

b. You need to show that all polynomials of order $<=n$ is a linear combination of monomials in $Q$.

c. Kernel of the map are elements that would be mapped to zero. In order for that to happen, we would be dealing with roots of $p(x)$. How many roots should $p(x)$ have?

d. I don't know what $c_k$ is but recall that a Lagrange polynomial is a polynomial that definitely goes through a prescribed number of points. Those prescribed number of points would be the column vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ space.

Solutions:
a. $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i + \sum_{i=0}^n b_i x^i = \sum_{i=0}^n (a_i+b_i)x^i$, $\alpha \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i = \sum_{i=0}^n (\alpha a_i) x^i$.

b. straight forward. pretty much by definition.

c. $p(x)$ has at most $n$ distinct roots by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, therefore one of the $n+1$ numbers $p(x_0), p(x_1), ... $ must be non-zero, hence the map has trivial kernel. (it cannot have no kernel, because the $0$ polynomial is in the kernel )

d. Just plug in the $n+1$ points into the Lagrange polynomial formula, I'm sure you saw it in class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I haven't look at the solutions yet, I'm just looking at the hints to see. c_k in the problem was just the formula for a Langrage Polynomial. The Pi product of (x - x_j)/(x_k - x_j) for k not equal to j. My bad I should have said that. So to clarify on that part, I would take the vector given in part c. (p_xo p_x1....p_x_n) and plug that into the formula I listed with the pi product? And that would find it?

Comment: Yup you take the column vector and just enter it into the Lagrange polynomial formula

Comment: Sounds great! I'll give it a shot! Thanks so much!